# GetArrayResult() With Many-To-Many Joins

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm joining a table using ManyToMany realationsships

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
$query->select("f.value value, f.description description, f.optionsValue 
                o.code optionCode, l.code localeCode")
                    ->leftJoin('f.locales', 'l')
                    ->leftJoin('f.options', 'o')
                     ....other joins

return $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
....
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Locale")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="w_file_values_locales",
 *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_value_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="locale_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @var ArrayCollection $locales
 */
private $locales;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Option")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="w_file_values_options",
 *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_value_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="option_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @var ArrayCollection $options
 */
private $options;
....
```

The problem is that the resulting Array doesn't return `localeCode` and `optionCode` as an Array of codes (strings) but returns only a string representing the first value of the 2 joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain what you are trying to do, but here is my guess.

You want the locales that are part of that main entity (referenced with `f`) in the output as an array in a field called `localeCode` and similar with options. Since it is an array and can be multiple I'd call the field `localeCodes` for output, or just `locales` as it is already called. If that's the case the following select portion should do the trick, while keeping the joins you have as well.

```php
$query->select("f.value value, f.description description, f.options optionCode, f.locales localeCode")
```